# Custom Classes: Custom type cannot be converted to other custom type

Tags: java, abstract-class, subclass

I have been given an assignment with two given classes, one abstract parent class Lot.java, and test class TestLots.java. I am not supposed to edit either of these. The assignment is to create two subclasses of Lot so that the errors in TestLots are no longer errors.

The purpose of the program is to display the name and area of the lots in order of are like this:

```
    Lot ID L3 has area: 13500.0 
    Lot ID L2 has area: 27000.0 
    Lot ID L1 has area: 35000.0 
    Lot ID L4 has area: 70000.0
```

However I get the errors: 
Incompatible types: LotType1 cannot be converted to Lot, and
LotType2 cannot be converted to Lot. I suspect the issue is in my subclass and the way it is supposed to override or reference the parent class.

Here is TestLots, where I get the error:

```
    public class TestLots {

        public static void main(String args[]){  
            // an array of lots -- some of type1, some of type2
            Lot[] lots = {new LotType1("L1",350, 200), // error here
                new LotType2("L2",100,270),
                new LotType1("L3",100, 270),
                new LotType2("L4",350,200)
            };

            // sort the lots of mixed types by area (note, you'll have to implement
            // Comparable interface correctly in LotType1 and LotType2 for this to work:
            java.util.Arrays.sort(lots);

            // print out sorted results
            for (Lot lot: lots) {
                System.out.print(lot + " "); 
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is Lot, the parent class

```
public abstract class Lot {

    public abstract double calculateArea();
    public abstract String getID();

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Lot ID "+ getID() +" has area: "+ calculateArea();
    }
}
```

The subclasses are nearly identical:

```
public class LotType1 extends Lot implements Comparable<LotType1>{
    String name;
    int height;
    int width;
    double area;

    public LotType1(String name, int height, int width) {
        this.name = name;
        this.height = height;
        this.width = width;
    }

    public String getID() {
        return name;
    }

    public double calculateArea() {
        return area = ((width * height)/2);
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(LotType1 lot) {
        area = ((width * height)/2);
        if(area==lot.area)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        else if(area>lot.area)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            return -1;
        }
    }
}
```

Edit to add LotType2:

```
public class LotType2 extends Lot implements Comparable<LotType2>{
    String name;
    int height;
    int width;
    double area;

    public LotType2(String name, int height, int width) {
        this.name = name;
        this.height = height;
        this.width = width;
    }

    public String getID() {
        return name;
    }

    public double calculateArea() {
        return area = (width * height);
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(LotType2 lot) {
        area = (width * height);
        if(area==lot.area)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        else if(area>lot.area)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            return -1;
        }
    }
}
```

Sorry this post is so long. I decided to include all of the relevant files in case that helps.

Comment: add the LotType2 class also.

commenting the LotType2 in the array definition. Its working fine.

Comment: The classes may be "nearly identical", but they're obviously not identical enough.  I tried it making `LotType2` identical to `LotType1` except for the name, and it compiles.  So there's obviously something different about `LotType2` that is causing the error, which means you need to post it.

Comment: Hi @Preshus HB, welcome to SO. If an answer helped you solve your problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the check mark next to the answer. .

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you can't sort objects with different comparable implementations in the same collection.  Change the subclass to implement Comparable of Lot  :

```
    public class LotType1 extends Lot implements Comparable<Lot> {
```

and also use calculateArea() in the compareTo method:

```
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Lot lot) {
        if (calculateArea() == lot.calculateArea()) {
            return 0;
        } else if (calculateArea() > lot.calculateArea()) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your full version of code is given below.

It will give you the expected result.

```
public class TestLots {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    // an array of lots -- some of type1, some of type2
    Lot[] lots = {new LotType1("L1", 350, 200), // error here
            new LotType2("L2", 100, 270),
            new LotType1("L3", 100, 270),
            new LotType2("L4", 350, 200)
    };

    // sort the lots of mixed types by area (note, you'll have to implement
    // Comparable interface correctly in LotType1 and LotType2 for this to work:
    java.util.Arrays.sort(lots);

    // print out sorted results
    for (Lot lot : lots) {
        System.out.print(lot + " ");
        System.out.println();
    }
}
}

abstract class Lot {

public abstract double calculateArea();

public abstract String getID();

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Lot ID " + getID() + " has area: " + calculateArea();
}
}


class LotType1 extends Lot implements Comparable<Lot> {
String name;
int height;
int width;
double area;

public LotType1(String name, int height, int width) {
    this.name = name;
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
}

public String getID() {
    return name;
}

public double calculateArea() {
    return area = ((width * height) / 2);
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Lot lot) {
    if (calculateArea() == lot.calculateArea()) {
        return 0;
    } else if (calculateArea() > lot.calculateArea()) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}
}

class LotType2 extends Lot implements Comparable<Lot> {
String name;
int height;
int width;
double area;

public LotType2(String name, int height, int width) {
    this.name = name;
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
}

public String getID() {
    return name;
}

public double calculateArea() {
    return area = ((width * height) / 2);
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Lot lot) {
    if (calculateArea() == lot.calculateArea()) {
        return 0;
    } else if (calculateArea() > lot.calculateArea()) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}
}
```